# how to import tibble in a package

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

So I have a function that creates a tibble from a couple of vectors. It works fine but when I try to run devtools::check() to check my package I get the following errors:

If I put no @importFrom statement and just a Depends for tidyverse I get the error:

```
Error in tibble(key = replace, val = replaceValue) : 
    could not find function "tibble"
```

If I put @importFrom tibble tibble I get the error:

```
Namespace dependency not required: 'tibble'
```

How do I get this function in as part of my own function within my package:

As it stands:

```
#' @param inputString The text string to process
#' @param list of words to iterate through
#' @keywords Withdrawal
#' @importFrom fuzzyjoin regex_left_join
#' @importFrom tibble tibble
#' @export

myfunction<-function(inputString,list){
  d1 <- tibble(key = replace, val = replaceValue)
}
```

Comment: `tibble::tibble`?

Comment: No luck with that @NelsonGon. I get the error: Error in tibble(key = .x) : could not find function "tibble"

Comment: Maybe use `as_tibble` from `dplyr`?!

Comment: Also where do you define replace and replaceValue?!